# Getting Cesium into my rails application based on these instructions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, cesiumjs

https://cesiumjs.org/tutorials/cesium-up-and-running/

See items 1-4 below.  I put items 1 and 2 into my application.html.erb  and items 3 and 4 into my view page and cannot get it running.  Anyone run into this?

[image: cesium page screenshot]

Comment: Yeah I'm a newbie, didn't drop in code, pardon my omission.  Code appears in the screenshot

Comment: have you code you can show us?

Comment: Thanks for responding - the issue I am having it turns out is with incorporating the following command into a rails app.  Any sense of how to do this - I'm told it is difficult?

Comment: @import url(rails/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css);

Comment: Try removing the whole `@import` line and add this to your HTML `<head>` section:  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="rails/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" type="text/css">`